# What language is used to program the BoardX?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

What language is used to program the [BoardX](http://www.upgradeindustries.com/category/1/BoardX/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Code [examples](http://www.upgradeindustries.com/product/18/ADC-X-Code-Examples) are in C.